# Show options of selected options inside the same <div>

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There is an unordered list of 3 items, say A,B and C inside a `<div>`. Now if I select an option A, it should again show a list of P, Q and R inside the same `<div>` and if I select B, it should show an unordered list of X,Y and Z plus it should have a back button as well.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</li>
        <li><a href="#">B</li>
        <li><a href="#">C</li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

Now upon selecting Option A, the following list should be displayed inside the same `<div>`

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">P</li>
        <li><a href="#">Q</li>
        <li><a href="#">R</li>
    </ul>
```

And like this, it is upto 3-4 levels down, for eg:- `From A->P,Q,R`. `From P->D,E,F`. `From D->S,R,T` and similarly. All should be displayed inside the same `<div>` tag.

I have searched bootstrap but didnt got the expected result. Can this be done in bootstrap. If not, how can I approach this problem in jQuery?

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tree view layout using jquery, try this code:

```
$('.tree li').each(function(){
        if($(this).children('ul').length > 0){
                $(this).addClass('parent');     
        }
});

$('.tree li.parent > a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Demo and Source: http://www.webstutorial.com/jquery-treeview-list/jquery

Comment: No. Thats not what I want. This is just show/hide functions with the parent list name still there. I want that child list name should overwrite the existing parent names in the same div